Hodge-Riemann form is non-degenerate
I'm studying Griffiths and Harris Principles of Algebraic Geometry. In particular I'm studying the Lefschetz Decomposition of a Kahler Manifold and its applications (pages 118-126).
After the proof of the Lefschetz decomposition, they give an application (pag 123):
they define a bilinear form
$$
Q: H^{n-k}(M) \otimes H^{n-k}(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}
$$
by setting
$$
Q(\xi, \eta)=\int_M \xi \wedge \eta \wedge \omega^k .
$$
Then they state the Hodge-Riemann bilinear relations:
for $\xi \in P^{p, q}(M)$ a primitive class and $k=p+q$ (I believe that here they meant "$n-k=p+q$"),
$$
\sqrt{-1}^{p-q}(-1)^{(n-k)(n-k-1) / 2} Q(\xi, \bar{\xi})>0 .
$$
Then they prove that $Q$ is a nondegenerate form on $P^{p+q}(M)$, and then they say that, since we have the Lefschetz decomposition
$$
H^m=\oplus L^k P^{m-2 k}
$$
and $Q\left(L^k \xi, L^k \eta\right)=Q(\xi, \eta)$, the bilinear relations tell us that $Q$ is nondegenerate on $H^{n-k}(M)$.
The question is: I understand the fact that $Q$ is a nondegenerate form on $P^{p+q}(M)$, but I don't undestand why it follows that it is nondegenerate on $H^{n-k}(M)$. I think that I need the fact that $Q\left(L^t \xi, L^k \eta\right)=0$ if $k \neq t$, is that true?

Let $\xi \in P^{n - k - 2i}$ and let $\eta \in P^{n - k - 2j}$, so that $L^i \xi \in H^{n - k}$ and $L^j \eta \in H^{n - k}$. Then we have
\begin{align*}Q(L^i\xi, L^j \eta) &= \int_M \omega^i \wedge \xi \wedge \omega^j \wedge \eta \wedge \omega^k\\
&= \pm \int_M \xi \wedge \eta \wedge \omega^{k + i + j}
\end{align*}
Now WLOG suppose $i > j$. We know that $L^{k + 2j + 1}P^{n - k - 2j} = 0$ from $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-rep theory (actually, this appears to be part of Griffiths-Harris's definition of primitive cohomology). Since $k + i + j > k + 2j$, we conclude that $0 = L^{k + i + j} \eta = \pm \eta \wedge \omega^{k + i + j}$. Hence $Q(L^i \xi, L^j \eta) = 0$ unless $i = j$.

Ok but how does this prove that $Q$ is non degenerate or that $Q\left(L^t \xi, L^k \eta\right)=0$ if $k \neq t$?

Sorry, I wasn't thinking properly. I've edited my answer to actually answer the question.

Thank you! In the last inequality you meant $k+i+j>k+2j$?

Yes, I've fixed it now.
